# Getting base64 binary video file and render it on UI but showing me a error on video file that is no video with supported format

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, multer

I have changed my video file to base64

```
var path ="video file path";  
let encodedData = fs.readFileSync(path).toString("base64");
```

and save it to mongo db

```
var obj = {    
 name: req.body.name,     
 desc: req.body.desc,     
 img: { data: fs.readFileSync("D:/Mongo-Image-Upload/uploads/video"),       
        contentType: "video/mp4",     
       },  
     };   

 imgSchema.create(obj).then((err, item) => {    
         if (err) { 
             console.log(err);     
               } else {  item.save(); 
                       res.redirect("/");   
                }
```

but after getting the binary data from db for video file On Ui it is showing me the no video with supported format error.
[image]

Comment: If you try play the video directly from your base64 file, i.e. no MongoDB middle-man, does that work?

Comment: sorry, but I didn't get your question. when I fetched the video buffer  from the mongodb. It is showing me the number array like this.
"data": [
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    32,
                    102,
                    116,
                    121,
                    112, ....]

Comment: I have tried to convert it to base64 but it didn't work.

Comment: Is that what's in `D:/Mongo-Image-Upload/uploads/video`?  Can you play what's in `D:/Mongo-Image-Upload/uploads/video`?  I'm wondering if MongoDB has anything to do with the issue.

Comment: nope I am not able to run. the file in the D:/Mongo-Image-Upload/uploads/video

Comment: Then storing `D:/Mongo-Image-Upload/uploads/video` in MongoDB isn't helpful is it?  Or do you have some way to _transform_ it into something playable?